# Using rsh from exec() Windows 2008 Server

Tags: php, windows-server-2008-r2, rsh

It seems many people have similar questions to this but none have been answered that fit what I am doing.

I am currently running apache and php on a Windows 2008 R2 server. From there I am trying to run an rsh command. Here is an example:

```
exec('rsh compname -l username "perl /mypath/server_info.pl"', $output, $status);
```

`$output` is always empty, and `$status` is always 0.

Prior to setting this up on this 2008 server, I had it working on a windows XP box with the same configuration. It connects the the same server with the same username and runs the same pl script. I can even open them both in a browser side by side and it works on the XP machine and not on the 2008 server.

Even if I run a command as simple as `ls` through rsh I get no output. Also it doesn't appear to be a php problem since if I just run

```
exec('ping servername',$output, $status);
```

I get the output expected.

Has anyone seen an issue like this or have any idea why rsh specifically is not sending its output?

Comment: Is rsh in your shell environment's %PATH%? Try using an absolute `c:/program files/rsh/rsh.exe -l ....` command instead if it's not.

Comment: Thanks, I just checked that and it already was in the `%PATH%` variable.

Comment: Don't forget this'll be running under the webserver's ID, so make sure it's in the path of whatever THAT account is.

Comment: Also good point, but yes that is the account I checked.